# unable to use script on kali llinux

Tags: bash, shell-script, kali-linux, mysql, nmap

```
#! /bin/bash

nmap sT 192.168.181.0/24 p 3306 >/dev/null oG MySQLscan
cat MySQLscan | grep open > MySQLscan2 
cat MySQLscan2
```

When i type this above script in text editor and save as `mysqlscanner.sh`, in kali linux, running in virtual box, the error is showing as mentioned below. (I do not have installed mysql in kali linux. Is this because I don't having mysql installed, that it is showing error?)

```
Failed to resolve "­sT".
Failed to resolve "­p".
Failed to resolve "­oG".
Failed to resolve "MySQLscan".
mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
Failed to resolve "MySQLscan".
```

Comment: You mean `-sT`, `-p` and `-oG`. If you are not familiar with this convention (which appears all over in Linux CLI really) then [consider beginning with a distro more friendly than Kali](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/108618) maybe.

Answer (score 2):

- Read the manual for `nmap`
- Learn about convention for command options: usually `-o`, or `--option`. i.e. `-sT`, `-p` and `-oG`.
- Find an easier distro: Kali is hard to use. However **it is not the cause of this problem**, but it will probably be the cause of your next one. It is designed for people with lots of experience.